# Use of requests.Response(...) with parameters

Tags: python-requests

There is a component in the [Runestone Book](http://interactivepython.org/) *Foundations of Python Programming* called `response_with_catching`. The code is available [here](https://github.com/presnick/RunestoneComponents/blob/master/runestone/activecode/js/requests_with_caching/__init__.py). The component prevent repeated calls to an API by saving responses and returning cached data when possible.

If cached data is available for an API call, this code is executed:

```
return requests.Response(permanent_cache[cache_key], full_url)
```

What is the purpose of this line?

There is no clear description in the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/) on how `request.response()` is used with parameters.

For example, in one particular run the parameters `permanent_cache` and `full_url` are:

```
permanent_cache[cache_key] = 
[{"word":"nappy","score":707,"numSyllables":2},
 {"word":"scrappy","score":702,"numSyllables":2}]

full_url = https://api.datamuse.com/words?rel_rhy=happy&max=2
```

There is a problem when the line is execute, for example, running

```
full_url = "https://api.datamuse.com/words?rel_rhy=happy&max=2"
x = requests.Response([{"word":"nappy","score":707,"numSyllables":2},
                       {"word":"scrappy","score":702,"numSyllables":2}], full_url)
```

Throws the error

`TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given`

Comment: Per the code you linked, there is a comment explaining what the line of code you're asking about is doing: "make a Response object containing text from the change, and the full_url that would have been fetched".

Comment: That's true, but it s not what I read in the documentation for the requests module!

Comment: I would trust in-code comments over documentation in this particular case.

Comment: Unfortunately the line throws an error when executed, so I'm reading the documentation, but there doesn't seems to be any examples illustrating this use of requests.Response(...)

Comment: This appears to be a possible bug in Runestone. Looking at the source code of the `requests.Response` class in the library, the constructor takes no arguments. I suggest opening an issue on the project, or searching  their current issues to see if it has been brought to their attention already.

Answer (score 0):

After additional research into the error thrown by the line `requests.response(...)` used in the [Runestone](http://interactivepython.org/) interactive book *Foundations of Python Programming*, it turns out that the book is not using the official python `requests` module. Rather, a restricted version is used, and the code listed for `response_with_catching` is not meant to be used in a full Python environment. This is not directly evident by reading comments in the code.